# Magento 2: How to change page layout from to 1column

Tags: magento2, page-layouts, column

What's up guys, i know this is some kind of basic question, but here's the thing, i can't change page layout from `catalog_product_view.xml` to 1column.
I've try using new custom theme, and EVERY content in that custom them is worked perfectly, but not with the `layout="1column"` in `catalog_product_view.xml`
Here is it:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\my-project\app\design\frontend\Gssi\jewellery\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- create new custom tab in product detail page -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
          <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" as="custom_tab" template="product/view/custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>

        <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.extrahint"></move>
    </body>
</page>
```

You see, every content in this file is worked. the `referenceBlock name="product.info.details"` work, the `move element="product.info.details"` work. But not with the `layout="1column"`.

Are there something in admin page that i need to check? I've searching everywhere but can't find anything ..
Any idea? Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried reindexing/recompiling ? sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: and is it a migration project ?

Comment: i was be told that di:compile does nothing, i never use di:compile :(

Comment: what is migration project?

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: this is my company project, i was tried to do the same thing on my testing project, i mean i've create custom theme, and it work with my testing project, but not with my company project, i still dont know why @@

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84121/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-fudu).

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/Gssi/jewellery/Magento_Catalog/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**Make sure you have registered and selected**

> custom theme from CONTENT->configuration

Comment: yes ofcouse i did, i also re deploy it :(

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so they use a special theme called porto, and i've to edit in admin to this work out :)
In porto->settings panel->product view
Thanks all for your help

Comment: ohhh man :D lol

Comment: i know right :) but its hard to find, i cant figure it out if my leader didn't tell me :(

Comment: It's okay bro :) sometime it happens

Comment: No worries :) that's how we learn and grow ! :)

Comment: you're welcome :)